# set form value with javascript geolocation

Tags: javascript, geolocation

Hello i am trying to log a users geolocation with javascript into a hidden form and then pass that form over to php to add to a database, so far i have it so it pass's the geo location and displays it onto the page but i cannot get it to be added into the value on a form post, heres the javascript.

```
    window.onload = function () {
var latElement = document.getElementById("lat");
var lonElement = document.getElementById("lon");
    getPositionOptions = {
        enableHighAccuracy: false,
        timeout: 10000,
    },
    getPos = function () {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var coords = position.coords;
            latElement.innerHTML = coords.latitude;
            lonElement.innerHTML = coords.longitude;
            setTimeout(getPos, 5000);
        },function (error){
            setTimeout(getPos, 5000);
        }, getPositionOptions);
    };
    getPos();
}
```

Ive tried set attribute etc i just cant get it to work i have one input for lat and another for lon. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the attribute value instead of innerHTML.
 like this:

> ```
> latElement.value=coords.latitude;
>   lonElement.value=coords.longitude;
> ```